# how to set various level ROW INDEX on a data table?

Tags: c#

I have a C# data table with below sample data,

[image]

Now, I am trying to add 3 more columns as row number (starts with zero in descending order) on 3 different level "Category" ("Grand_Total", "Overall_Total" and "PROJ_TOTAL"), here is I'm trying to achieve,
[image]

I able to add ONLY one column "G_T_I" with total number of rows in datatable logic, but not able to figure out the logic to crack other 2 columns "O_T_I" and "P_T_I".
Please help/suggest?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the DataTable.
        DataTable table = GetTable();

        //get new data table 
        DataTable newTable = GetNewTable();

        for(int i = table.Rows.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            var gTotalIndex = (table.Rows.Count - i) - 1;
            newTable.Rows.Add(i, table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Category"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Name"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["PROJID"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Type"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Amt"]);
        }

    }

    static DataTable GetNewTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("G_T_I", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("PROJID", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Amt", typeof(decimal));
        return table;
    }

    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("PROJID", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Amt", typeof(decimal));

        table.Rows.Add("NEW_PROJ", "ABC", "100", "Acost", 10);
        table.Rows.Add("SAME_PROJ", "", "", "Bcost", 20);
        table.Rows.Add("PROJ_TOTAL", "", "100 Total", "", 30);
        table.Rows.Add("NEW_PROJ", "", "200", "Acost", 40);
        table.Rows.Add("PROJ_TOTAL", "", "200 Total", "", 40);
        table.Rows.Add("OVERALL_TOTAL", "ABC Total", "", "", 70);
        table.Rows.Add("NEW_PROJ", "PQR", "300", "Acost", 10);
        table.Rows.Add("SAME_PROJ", "", "", "Bcost", 10);
        table.Rows.Add("PROJ_TOTAL", "", "300 Total", "", 20);
        table.Rows.Add("OVERALL_TOTAL", "PQR Total", "", "", 20);
        table.Rows.Add("GRAND_TOTAL", "", "", "", 90);

        return table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get the DataTable.
            DataTable table = GetTable();

            //get new data table 
            DataTable newTable = GetNewTable();

            for (int i = table.Rows.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                var gTotalIndex = (table.Rows.Count - i) - 1;
                newTable.Rows.Add(i,null,null, table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Category"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Name"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["PROJID"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Type"], table.Rows[gTotalIndex]["Amt"]);
            }

            var oTotal = 0;
            for (int i = newTable.Rows.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                if (newTable.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString() == "GRAND_TOTAL")
                    continue;
                if (newTable.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString() == "OVERALL_TOTAL")
                {
                    oTotal = 0;
                    newTable.Rows[i]["O_T_I"] = oTotal;
                    oTotal++;
                }
                else
                {
                    newTable.Rows[i]["O_T_I"] = oTotal;
                    oTotal++;
                }
            }

            var pTotal = 0;
            for (int i = newTable.Rows.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                if (newTable.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString() == "GRAND_TOTAL" || newTable.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString() == "OVERALL_TOTAL")
                    continue;
                if (newTable.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString() == "PROJ_TOTAL")
                {
                    pTotal = 0;
                    newTable.Rows[i]["P_T_I"] = pTotal;
                    pTotal++;
                }
                else
                {
                    newTable.Rows[i]["P_T_I"] = pTotal;
                    pTotal++;
                }
            }

        }

        static DataTable GetNewTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("G_T_I", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("O_T_I", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("P_T_I", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("PROJID", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Amt", typeof(decimal));
            return table;
        }

        static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("PROJID", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Amt", typeof(decimal));

            table.Rows.Add("NEW_PROJ", "ABC", "100", "Acost", 10);
            table.Rows.Add("SAME_PROJ", "", "", "Bcost", 20);
            table.Rows.Add("PROJ_TOTAL", "", "100 Total", "", 30);
            table.Rows.Add("NEW_PROJ", "", "200", "Acost", 40);
            table.Rows.Add("PROJ_TOTAL", "", "200 Total", "", 40);
            table.Rows.Add("OVERALL_TOTAL", "ABC Total", "", "", 70);
            table.Rows.Add("NEW_PROJ", "PQR", "300", "Acost", 10);
            table.Rows.Add("SAME_PROJ", "", "", "Bcost", 10);
            table.Rows.Add("PROJ_TOTAL", "", "300 Total", "", 20);
            table.Rows.Add("OVERALL_TOTAL", "PQR Total", "", "", 20);
            table.Rows.Add("GRAND_TOTAL", "", "", "", 90);

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @King...I tried your above solution, all Index are either 0 or 1 ONLY. Could you please post complete solution, I suppose U are updating Index rather than return a new Data Table by adding Index columns. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @user584018 sorry, i have fixed it, there is a mistake in it.